# Where is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm migrating my own TFS logging extension to VS 2015 and run into many dependency issues. Most of them I was able to get rid off by installing [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) nuget package.

However there's still one missing reference, the `VersionControlExt`class

```
versionControlExt =
                    _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt")
                    as VersionControlExt;
```

According to documentation, it is located in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll`, but I can't find this file at all. Does anyone know where to get it from or how to change the above code to get it working with VS 2015?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional, 14.0.23107.0 D14REL version.

Comment: It is stored in the GAC on my machine, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a directory.  Filedate is July 30 2015, must have gotten there through the VS2015 installer.  It has the VesionControlExt class.  The edition you are using does matter, don't omit that from the question.  And show the trace you get from Fuslogvw.exe

Comment: I added the edition details in the question. FusLogVw gives me nothing, as   I can't even add reference in Visual Studio. I found this library deep in Visual Studio folder structure as well as in GAC, exactly where You pointed, but still am unable to add it as a reference to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found the issue.

The one that is in GAC (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl\`)  is the old version (11.0.50727.1) of the library. It gets there with VS 2015 installation, but it isn't the right one.

The one that is used by Visual Studio Team Explorer extension is located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\oglzibax.qr0\`. It's version is 14.0.23102.0.

While I was trying to use the old one, I was constantly getting `MissingMethodException`.

Comment: Note: the last folder hash containing this assembly can differ. I found mine using [Everything](http://voidtools.com/)

Answer (score 3):

For VS 2015, you can find its location by navigating to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer. If you go there and then go up one directory you will see that Team Explorer is a symbolic link to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ftq4t4pd.guv (in my case). So it’s like instead of shipping the DLLs with the product they ship them in an extension and whenever the extension updates they update that symbolic link to point at it. Very odd.

For VS 2017, you can find it by navigating to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer, replacing "Professional" with whatever version you have installed. It doesn't appear VS 2017 has the symbolic link thing going on.

Comment: This one did it for me: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer