# Where is VersionControlExt in Visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility, tfs-2015

I 'm doing porting for an addin from visual studio 2013 to visual studio 2015.

In Visual Studio 2013 I called

```
vce = dte2.GetObject(typeof(VersionControlExt).FullName) as VersionControlExt;
vce.Explorer.Workspace.PendEdit(file);
```

and with versionControlExt I can keep in checkout the files.

In visual I can not find something equivalent.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet ? I haven't searched it myself for the thing to replace `VersionControlExt`, but these libraries are suggested to use by MS.

Comment: Google "versioncontrolext vs2015" and you'll have no trouble finding [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438852/where-is-microsoft-visualstudio-teamfoundation-versioncontrol-dll-in-visual-stud).

Answer (score 0):

VersionControlExt Class is located in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll. On my computer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll locates in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\w35fwkfc.rm2, you can try to find it under a similar path.

I have tested on my side, after adding reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\w35fwkfc.rm2, and using it in project, VersionControlExt Class can be recognized.