# Where is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am updating solution from VS2013 to VS2015.

But I have problem to find one dll in VS2015.

It is **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll**

All other dll-s I included with nuget packages, and I have tham in Visual Studio instalation folder.

Do I need some nugget package to get this reference? 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438852/where-is-microsoft-visualstudio-teamfoundation-versioncontrol-dll-in-visual-stud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to integrate TFS into your project using NuGet, you have to install the following packages (depending on your integration level):

- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)
- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/)

Comment: I have done all that and still missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll

Comment: Also same problem with Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll