# How do I pick up the selected source file in a visual studio extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-package

I am writing have a visual studio extension.

What I want to do is run a menu option (ok done this) which picks up the file I have selected using the source control explorer and works with it.

Any Ideas how I can get this file?
I really need the file itself and the TFS path $/....

This is not the selected file in "Solution Explorer".

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like this:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt versionControl =
                DTE.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt")
            as Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt;
string file = versionControl.Explorer.CurrentFolderItem.SourceServerPath;
```

See [Browse one folder up in Sorce Control Explorer](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#sce_up) for a complete sample.

Comment: That looks just right but I don't get a reference to TeamFoundation
I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

What do I need to install otherwise to get that?

Comment: @KevinBadger See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438852/where-is-microsoft-visualstudio-teamfoundation-versioncontrol-dll-in-visual-stud